# How do I override the java.exe in windows32

Tags: java, windows, installation

I have a couple versions of java installed (6u32 and 7u21) and recently installed another version (6u37).  I have my path variable set JAVA_HOME to a path to my java 7 folder, but after restarting my console `java -version` still returns `java version "1.6.0_37"`.

EDIT
JAVA_HOME is set in the user variables.  So it gets appended at the end of the system variables.

I am guessing that the java.exe in the windows32 folder is version 6u37.  In my path Windows32 appears before JAVA_HOME.  How do I override the recently installed version of java with the one I set in java home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your system `PATH` environment variable to reflect the new installation directory.

`JAVA_HOME` is used by Java once its running, while `PATH` is used by Windows to determine where exe's are located.